# Normalizing a sum of rectangle functions

Tags: probability, functions, inequality

Consider the (non-normalized) distribution
$$f(x)=\text{rect}\left(\frac{x+s/2}{L}\right)+\text{rect}\left(\frac{x-s/2}{L}\right). $$
If $l$ is sufficiently small, the two rectangle functions overlap and sum to $2$. What is the correct normalization factor $\mathcal N$ by which $f(x)$ needs to be multiplied in order to ensure $f(x)=1$ for all points that lie in one, or both, of the rectangles, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise?

Comment: Please define your function "rect" : there are different definitions ! Is it : rect(t)=1 if $-1/2<t<1/2$, rect(t)=0 elsewhere ?

Comment: I'm going by the Wikipedia definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function).

Comment: Otherwise said, it is the definition I have guessed...

Comment: @JeanMarie I'd like to rescale $f$ to a function $\tilde f(x)=\frac{f(x)}{\mathcal N}$ that has values in $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I edited the question for clarity: I want the function to be one whenever the first or second are one, essentially. Without a normalization factor, $f$ has value $2$ in their intersection (if it is non-emtpy).

Comment: @JeanMarie I really don't. I'm looking for $\mathcal N=\mathcal N(s,L)$ such that $f(x)/\mathcal N$ is one for $x$ in the union of the rectangles and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a post-processing function $f$ such that :

$$f(0)=0, f(1)=1, f(2)=1,$$

use function `sign` in the following way :

take $f(x)=\frac12(\operatorname{sign}(x-\tfrac12)+1)$

Explanation : I subtract $\frac12$ to the given value in order to have a clear-cut result, i.e, values which are $-1$ and $1$ resp. for values outside, resp. inside the union ; then the two last operations achieve the transformation of set $\{-1,1\}$ into set $\{0,1\}$.

[image]

```
 clear all;close all;hold on;
 set(gcf,'color','w')
 rec=@(x)(abs(x)<0.5);
 L=3;s=2;
 g=@(x)(rec((x-s/2)/L)+rec((x+s/2)/L));
 n=@(u)(sign(u-0.5)+1)/2;
 x=-5:0.01:5;
 plot(x,g(x),'r','LineWidth',5);hold on;
 plot(x,n(g(x)),'b','LineWidth',2);
```

Comment: Just added a graphical representation (blue function obtained out of the red one)

Comment: Any comment ? ...